# Uderstanding GC logs and delays in the web application

Tags: java, web-applications, garbage-collection

This is a GC logs of webapp (JBoss 7.1). How to interpret this information? 
Webapp sometimes has noticeable delays and I try to find the reason.

```
362.261: [GC [PSYoungGen: 12772K->677K(13056K)] 47780K->35813K(57600K), 0.0214030 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
375.011: [GC [PSYoungGen: 12965K->537K(13056K)] 48101K->36056K(57600K), 0.0410890 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.04 secs]
377.211: [GC [PSYoungGen: 12823K->764K(12800K)] 48342K->36391K(57344K), 0.0774440 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.08 secs]
400.197: [GC [PSYoungGen: 12796K->777K(13056K)] 48423K->36464K(57600K), 0.0204340 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
...
4222.821: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 4096K->0K(8704K)] [ParOldGen: 55161K->40145K(55552K)] 59257K->40145K(64256K) [PSPermGen: 52107K->52107K(87552K)], 1.0148930 secs] [Times: user=0.79 sys=0.01, real=1.02 secs]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Times: user=0.79 sys=0.01, real=1.02 secs]` - is a summary of Stop-the-World pause. For 1.02 secs of wallclock time all application threads were suspended (thus all HTTP request being processed were delayed).

"Full GC" means major GC when both young and old space is collected. Just "GC" is minor GC, only garbage in young space is collected (thus StW pause is shorter).

You can find more information about GC algorithm available in HotSpot JVM [here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/12/garbage-collection-in-hotspot-jvm.html). If you curious about what is happening during StW pause take a look at [this](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/06/understanding-gc-pauses-in-jvm-hotspots.html) article.

Comment: Does it mean that increasing internal calculations and/or more content processing in webapp will mean an increase in growth StW time and frequency? Also for example application has 512Mb memory limit, so does it mean that StW pauses will be bigger and often compared to application with 2Gb memory limit?

Comment: Can we assume that the GC can not be the cause of noticeable delays in a web application?

Comment: @Andy What does noticeable means? I see Full GC taking 1 second. If delay is 10 seconds, then GC is not a cause. 512 Mb Vs. 2 Gb - mathematics is not what simple. In general, more memory -> less frequient but StW. But this is great oversimplification.