# Openshift: application is not responding

Tags: openshift

I have a webapp which is quite often does not respond to request. There are no errors in logs. I do not think that it is application errors. But what is the cause of this? Note, all that happens even before any application controller action.
This is a service info:

```
“oo-cgroup-read cpu.cfs_period_us”
100000
“oo-cgroup-read cpu.cfs_quota_us”
100000
“oo-cgroup-read cpu.rt_period_us”
1000000
“oo-cgroup-read cpu.rt_runtime_us”
0
“oo-cgroup-read cpu.shares”
128
“oo-cgroup-read cpu.stat”
nr_periods 4422171
nr_throttled 2640
throttled_time 123367550142
“oo-cgroup-read cpuacct.stat”
user 240149
system 115230
“oo-cgroup-read cpuacct.usage”
5286207717468
“oo-cgroup-read cpuacct.usage_percpu”
2765304828137 2521009189993
“oo-cgroup-read freezer.state”
THAWED
“oo-cgroup-read memory.failcnt”
0
“oo-cgroup-read memory.limit_in_bytes”
536870912
“oo-cgroup-read memory.max_usage_in_bytes”
360595456
“oo-cgroup-read memory.memsw.failcnt”
0
“oo-cgroup-read memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes”
641728512
“oo-cgroup-read memory.memsw.max_usage_in_bytes”
441470976
“oo-cgroup-read memory.memsw.usage_in_bytes”
359337984
“oo-cgroup-read memory.move_charge_at_immigrate”
1
“oo-cgroup-read memory.oom_control”
oom_kill_disable 1
under_oom 0
“oo-cgroup-read memory.soft_limit_in_bytes”
9223372036854775807
“oo-cgroup-read memory.stat”
cache 13938688
rss 207360000
mapped_file 2879488
pgpgin 3820067
pgpgout 3766039
swap 137932800
inactive_anon 101171200
active_anon 106188800
inactive_file 7163904
active_file 6770688
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 536870912
hierarchical_memsw_limit 641728512
total_cache 13938688
total_rss 207360000
total_mapped_file 2879488
total_pgpgin 3820067
total_pgpgout 3766039
total_swap 137932800
total_inactive_anon 101171200
total_active_anon 106188800
total_inactive_file 7163904
total_active_file 6770688
total_unevictable 0
“oo-cgroup-read memory.swappiness”
70
“oo-cgroup-read memory.usage_in_bytes”
221319168
“oo-cgroup-read memory.use_hierarchy”
0
“oo-cgroup-read net_cls.classid”
69307
“oo-cgroup-read notify_on_release”
0
“oo-cgroup-read tasks”
373
```

A response time graph with 1 minute interval and Timeout 4000 ms.
[image]
[image]

Here is a related and maybe helpfull question [Uderstanding GC logs and delays in the web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29076116/uderstanding-gc-logs-and-delays-in-the-web-application)

> Daily report:
>   Daily uptime: 95.56%, Downtime: 17 min(s) 50 sec(s)

Comment: What type of application is it? What cartridges are you using? Are you using a database?  Are you using a custom domain alias? Are you using a dns forwarding service?

Comment: @corey112358 It is Java type application, Jboss 7.1 server and MySQL database (a free plan). There is no custom domain alias and no dns forwarding service.